# The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\5-23-2011.log' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, filestream

I have a singleton logger which is used inside an ASP.NET application. Sometimes I get `The process cannot access the file` error on this line:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Path to log file", true);
```

I checked file handle by [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and `w3wp.exe` owns the handle so it seems different threads from the same process caused the problem.

I have used a `lock` around the above code, but still I get the error.
How can I make sure all threads can use the same stream safely?

Comment: What are you locking on?  Please add the line that contains the lock statement.

Comment: Why not just go with an existing logging library and save yourself these headaches? There's log4net, elmah, MS enterprise logging application block...

Comment: I created a new question and added the full source code under it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092543/singleton-compact-logger-for-asp-net-applications

Comment: @nickyt: I tried many of them and just referencing a logger like `EntLib` added 8 MB assemblies to my code. I need a light logger. You can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092543/singleton-compact-logger-for-asp-net-applications

Comment: do you have web gardens enabled on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Don't open the log file more than once; just open it when the application starts, close it at exit (and flush it often.) Opening and closing more than once is just inefficient.