# Singleton compact Logger for ASP.NET applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, singleton

I have coded a `Singeton` compact logger which is very handy for `ASP.NET` applications. Just refrencing it and then `Logger.Log.Info("Hello world!");`. It also logs unhandled exceptions automatically.

Sometimes I get error where I try to create the log file `Stream`.

The exception is:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Logs\5-22-2011.log' because it is being used by another process..

I checked with Process Explorer and only w3wp.exe has handle over the log file. It seems different threads made the problem. This happens about every 24h!

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: @ChrisWue: `The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\Logs\5-22-2011.log' because it is being used by another process.`. I checked with `Process Explorer` and only `w3wp.exe` has handle over the log file. It seems different threads made the problem. This happens about every 24h!

Comment: possible duplicate of [The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApp\5-23-2011.log' because it is being used by another process.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092421/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-c-inetpub-wwwroot-myapp-5-23-2011-log-becau)

Comment: you should update your question instead of creating duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's happening periodically, you might want to check the IIS settings and see if the application pool is being recycled at 24h intervals. (I think from memory the default is 29h)

If this is the case, your problem could be caused by IIS 'spinning up' a new app pool while the old one is still handling requests (overlapped recycling - which is the default behaviour), i.e. a new Logger is attempting to instantiate in a new process before the old one has had its destructor called.

Edit: Forgot to mention (it was late when I wrote the answer), that one way to mitigate this would be to change the log filename to include the full date AND time.

Comment: Yep, this is the first thing that comes to mind. A single w3wp.exe can host several app domains, and in this case this kind of clash can happen.

Comment: Right. That was the case (default recycling interval is 29h, wondering why not 24h). This way many libraries need change before using in ASP.NET